# Use Lookup and For Each Iteration to pull data from different analytics.dev.azure.com projects

Tags: azure-data-factory

Hi would just like to ask if this is possible, I am currently working on ADF, what I want to do is get workitems from analytics.dev.azure.com/[Organization]/[Project] then copy it to SQL Database. i am currently already doing this for 1 project, but want to do it for multiple projects without creating multiple copyto tasks within ADF but just run a Lookup to ForEach to iterate through all the team analytics URLs, is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use lookup and for-each activity to copy data to SQL dB tables from all URLs. Below are the steps

1. Create a lookup table which contains the entire list of URLs and use this table as a source dataset in lookup activity.

[image]

2. Next in for each activity's settings, type the following in items for getting output of lookup activity

`@activity('Lookup1').output.value`

[image]

3. Inside for each activity, use copy activity.

[image]

4. In source, create a dataset and http linked service. Enter the base URL and relative URL. I have stored relative URLs in lookup activity. Thus I have given `@{item().url}` in relative URL

[image]

5. In sink, Create azure SQL database table for each item in for each activity or use the existing tables and copy data to those tables.

Comment: where do I create this first URL table? should I create a dataset?

Comment: You can create lookup table in azure blob storage itself or any other storage you use.  Yes. You have to create dataset for that.

Comment: i need to also enter Personal Access Tokens for each URL with their corresponding Tokens, how do i do that in the linked service? thanks

Comment: This seems to be out of my knowledge. Please create a new post with this question on it, so that the community may assist you.